# Angular2: How to enable save button if any model value changed on edit page

Tags: angular2-template, angular2-components

I am new for angular 2. I have a page where we can edit details of customer profile. How to enable save button if any property of has been changed. I know it is possible in angular1 by using $watch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I resolved this issue.

```
import { Component, Input, Output, OnInit, AfterViewInit, EventEmitter, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'subscribe-modification',
  templateUrl: './subscribe.component.html'
})

export class SampleModifyComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
disableSaveSampleButton: boolean = true;
@ViewChild('sampleModifyForm') sampleForm;

ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
            this.sampleForm.control.valueChanges.subscribe(values => this.enableSaveSampleButton());
    }, 1000);
}

enableSaveSampleButton() {
    console.log('change');
    this.disableSaveSampleButton = false;
   }
}



HTML
<button id="btnSave" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="save()" />
```

Answer (score 2):

It is simple. `dirty` check your form if you are using  `@angular/forms`.

**create form**

```
export class HeroDetailComponent4 {
  heroForm: FormGroup;
  states = states;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.createForm();
  }

  createForm() {
    this.heroForm = this.fb.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required ],
      street: '',
      city: '',
      state: '',
      zip: '',
      power: '',
      sidekick: ''
    });
  }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
    <h2>Hero Detail</h2>
    <h3><i>A FormGroup with multiple FormControls</i></h3>
    <form [formGroup]="heroForm" novalidate>
<button (click)="submit()" [disabled]="!heroForm.dirty" type="button">Submit</button>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="center-block">Name:
          <input class="form-control" formControlName="name">
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="center-block">Street:
          <input class="form-control" formControlName="street">
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="center-block">City:
          <input class="form-control" formControlName="city">
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="center-block">State:
          <select class="form-control" formControlName="state">
              <option *ngFor="let state of states" [value]="state">{{state}}</option>
          </select>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="center-block">Zip Code:
          <input class="form-control" formControlName="zip">
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group radio">
        <h4>Super power:</h4>
        <label class="center-block"><input type="radio" formControlName="power" value="flight">Flight</label>
        <label class="center-block"><input type="radio" formControlName="power" value="x-ray vision">X-ray vision</label>
        <label class="center-block"><input type="radio" formControlName="power" value="strength">Strength</label>
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label class="center-block">
          <input type="checkbox" formControlName="sidekick">I have a sidekick.
        </label>
      </div>
    </form>
```

use `heroForm.dirty` to check whether form data is changed. it will set to `true` if any control inside `heroForm` has been changed.

```
<button (click)="submit()" [disabled]="!heroForm.dirty" type="button">Submit</button>
```

Refer [angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) for more info

Answer (score 2):

you can use form control validation for it.
some thing like this in html template:

```
 <form fxLayout="column" [formGroup]="form">
          <mat-form-field class="mb-1">
            <input matInput [(ngModel)]="userProfileChangeModel.firstName" placeholder="نام"
                   [formControl]="form1.controls['fname']">
            <small *ngIf="form1.controls['fname'].hasError('required') && form1.controls['fname'].touched"
                   class="mat-text-warn">لطفا نام را وارد نمایید.
            </small>
            <small *ngIf="form1.controls['fname'].hasError('minlength') && form1.controls['fname'].touched"
                   class="mat-text-warn">نام باید حداقل 2 کاراکتر باشد.
            </small>
            <small *ngIf="form1.controls['fname'].hasError('pattern') && form1.controls['fname'].touched"
                   class="mat-text-warn">لطفا از حروف فارسی استفاده نمائید.
            </small>

          </mat-form-field>
           <mat-card-actions>
            <button mat-raised-button (click)="editUser()" color="primary" [disabled]="!form1.valid" type="submit">
              ذخیره
            </button>
          </mat-card-actions>
        </form>
```

and like this in ts file:

```
    this.form = this.bf.group({
  fname: [null, Validators.compose([
    Validators.required,
    Validators.minLength(2),
    Validators.maxLength(20),
    Validators.pattern('^[\u0600-\u06FF, \u0590-\u05FF]*$')])],
});
```

if:

```
[disabled]="!form1.valid"
```

is valid save button will be active

bast regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can use disabled option like below :

```
  <button [disabled]="isInvalid()" type="button" (click) = "searchClick()" class="button is-info">
          <span class="icon is-small">
            <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </span>
          <span>Search</span>
     </button>
```

you can create isInvalid() in your ts file and check if that property is empty or not and return that boolean value

Comment: i have below component and i want to enable submit button if change in name/address or postcode.
export class customer implements OnInit {
 name: string;
 address: string;
 postcode: string;
 
 constructor() {}


 ngOnInit() {} 
}

Answer (score 0):

and for hide button on a state you can use *ngIf in line directive.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, pls try.
In your html,

```
<input type="text" [ngModel]="name" (ngModelChange)="changeVal()" >
<input type="text" [ngModel]="address" (ngModelChange)="changeVal()" >
<input type="text" [ngModel]="postcode" (ngModelChange)="changeVal()" >

<button [disabled]="noChangeYet" (click)="clicked()" >
  <span>SUBMIT</span>
</button>
```

In your component

```
export class customer implements OnInit { 
  name: string; 
  address: string; 
  postcode: string;
  noChangeYet:boolean = true;

  constructor() {} 

  changeVal(){ // triggers on change of any field(s)
    this.noChangeYet = false;
  }

  clicked(){
    // your function data after click (if any)
  } 
}
```

Hope this is what you need.

Comment: Thanks Veena! is it possible to do it without (ngModelChange)="changeVal()" because I have co many controls and don't want to add it for all of controls.

Comment: @VindhyachalKumar are you using any forms or form groups to bind all these input fields?? or are all of these input fields are independent ?